# Real Analysis, Folland Problem 5.3.29 The Baire Category Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The Baire Category Theorem - Let $X$ be a complete metric space

a.) If $\{U_n\}_1^\infty$ is a sequence of open dense subsets of $X$, then $\bigcap_1^\infty U_n$ is dense in $X$.

b.) $X$ is not a countable union of nowhere dense sets.

The name for this theorem comes from Baire's terminology for sets: If $X$ is a topological space, a set $E\subset X$ if of the first category, or meager, according to Baire, if $E$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets; otherwise $E$ is of the second category.

> Let $\mathscr{Y} = L^1(\mu)$ where $\mu$ is counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$, and let $\mathscr{X} = \{f\in \mathscr{Y}:\sum_{1}^{\infty}n|f(n)| < \infty \}$ equipped with the $L^1$ norm.
>
> a.) $X$ is a proper dense subset of $\mathscr{Y}$; hence $X$ is not complete.
>
> b.) Define $T:\mathscr{X}\rightarrow \mathscr{Y}$ by $Tf(n) = nf(n)$. Then $T$ is closed but not bounded.
>
> c.) Let $S = T^{-1}$. Then $S: \mathscr{Y}\rightarrow \mathscr{X}$ is bounded and surjective but not open.

Proof of a.) Clearly $0\in \mathscr{X}$. If $f,g\in \mathscr{X}$ and $a\in K$ then $$\sum_{1}^{\infty}n|(f+ag)(n)| = \sum_{1}^{\infty}n|f(n) + ag(n)| \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}n|f(n)| + \sum_{1}^{\infty}n|ag(n)| = \sum_{1}^{\infty}n|f(n)| + |a|\sum_{1}^{\infty}n|g(n)| < \infty$$ So $\mathscr{X}$ is a subspace of $\mathscr{Y}$. Since $\sum_{1}^{\infty}n^{-2}$ converges but $\sum_{1}^{\infty}n^{-1}$ does not, the map $n\rightarrow n^{-2}$ is in $\mathscr{Y}\setminus \mathscr{X}$. Let $f\in mathscr{Y}$ and $\epsilon\in (0,\infty)$. There exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|f(n)| < \epsilon$. It follows that $$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|f(n) - n^{-1}f(n)| = \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}(1 - n^{-1})|f(n)|\leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|f(n)| < \epsilon$$ which implies that $\lVert f - g\rVert < \epsilon$, where $g\in \mathscr{X}$ is defined by $$g(n) := \begin{cases}
f(n) & \text{if } n < N\\
n^{-1}f(n) & \text{if } n\geq N
\end{cases}$$
This shows that $\mathscr{X}$ is a proper dense subset of $\mathscr{Y}$, so $\overline{\mathscr{X}} = \mathscr{Y}\neq \mathscr{X}$ and hence $\mathscr{X}$ is not complete.

proof of b.) no idea

proof of c.) Clearly $Sf(n) = n^{-1}f(n)$ for all $f\in \mathscr{Y}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It follows that $$\lVert S f\rVert = \sum_{1}^{\infty}|Sf(n)| = \sum_{1}^{\infty}|n^{-1}f(n)| = \sum_{1}^{\infty}n^{-1}|f(n)| \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}|f(n)| = \lVert f\rVert$$ for all $f\in\mathscr{Y}$, so $S$ is bounded. Since $S = T^{-1}$, it is obvious that $S$ is surjective. If $S$ were open then $T$ would be continuous, which contradict b.).

I know it may seem strange that I can prove a and c but not b but I am not exactly sure how to proceed with b, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did not you take $a,b \in K$ and then show that $af+bg \in X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (a), a yet shorter proof is that the subspace of $\mathscr{Y}$ which consists of sequences with finitely many non-zero entries is dense in $\mathscr{Y}$.

For part (b), let the sequence $\{x_i\}$ be such that $x_i \in \mathscr{D}(T)$ for all $i$, and $x_i\to x$ and $Tx_i\to y$ as $i\to \infty$. To show that $T$ is closed, we need to prove that $x\in \mathscr{D}(T)$, and $Tx=y$. But for each $n$, $x_i(n) \to x(n)$ and $nx_i(n) \to y(n)$ as $i\to \infty$. That is, $nx(n) = y(n)$, which finishes the proof.

Comment: Can you explicitly show the proof for part a), please?

Comment: @Ninja If you are still interested: Given any $y\in \mathscr{Y}$, let $y_n \in \mathscr{Y}$ be such that its first $n$ entries is the same as $y$, and the rest are zero. Then $y_n\to y$, so the subspace is dense.