# An Application of Open Mapping theorem and counting measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Related to [Real Analysis, Folland Problem 5.3.29 The Baire Category Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1706009):

The question above is taken from Folland's Real Analysis. The user has written some of his work related to the problem but it seems like he taken everything exactly  from [this solution manual](https://math24.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/ch5-folland.pdf). I am working on the related topics these days and I want to completely understand how to prove this exercise. I could not get any reply from the user who asked the question and the only user who answered this question. So, if it is not wrong, I want to ask this question again since it is a "dead question".

First,

**Open Mapping Theorem.** Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. If $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is surjective, then $T$ is open.

Now, the exercise:

> **Exercise.** Let $Y = L^{1}(\mu)$ where $\mu$  is counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$ and let $X= \{f \in Y: \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n|f(n)| < \infty$ }, equipped with $L^1$ norm. Then,
>
> **a.** $X$ is a proper dense subspace of $Y$; hence $X$ is not complete.
>
> **b**.Define $T:X \rightarrow Y$ by $Tf(n)=nf(n)$. Then $f$ is closed but not bounded.
>
> **c.** Let $S = T^{-1}$. Then $S: Y \to X$ is bounded and surjective but not open.

How do we prove this exercise in the most explicit way?

**i)** For example why do not we start to prove that $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ by showing that $f,g \in X; a,b \in K \implies af+bg \in X?$

**ii)** What is $Y$ exactly? Is it just a bunch of functions $f$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n) < \infty$?

Comment: You can prove $X$ is a subspace directly from the triangle inequality, and one generally avoids such routine calculations when there are bigger things to worry about. As for $Y$, this is usually denoted by $\ell^1$, or $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ - ie. sequences of numbers which form absolutely convergent series.

Comment: Yes, I proved it but I took $2$ constants from $K=\mathbb{C}$. I am confused with the proof that is given since it only has 1 constant. Is it correct to take 2 constants?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, also do you know any notes that contains this $Y$ space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I did not reply I changed the proof around from what I posted, and yes I should have noted I got the original proof from that pdf you posted, I was using it to try to prove it on my own.

a.) Clearly $0\in \mathcal{X}$. If $f,g\in \mathcal{X}$ and $a\in K$ then $$\sum_{1}^{\infty}n|(f+ag)(n)| = \sum_{1}^{\infty}n|f(n) + ag(n)| \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}n|f(n)| + \sum_{1}^{\infty}n|ag(n)| = \sum_{1}^{\infty}n|f(n)| + |a|\sum_{1}^{\infty}n|g(n)| < \infty$$ So $\mathcal{X}$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{Y}$.

Now if $f\in \mathcal{Y}$ and we define $g_{k}(n) = f(n)$ if $n \leq k$ and  $g_{k}(n) = 0$ if $n > k$ then $g_k\in\mathcal{X}$ and, since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|f(n)|<\infty$,
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \int |g_k - f|d\mu = \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |g_k(n) - f(n)|= \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}|f(n)|= 0$$
So if $k\to \infty$ then $g_k\to f$ and thus $\mathcal{X}$ is dense in $\mathcal{Y}$.

b.) Note that $T$ is clearly linear. Let $\{f_n\}_{1}^{\infty}\in\mathcal{X}$ that converges to $f\in \mathcal{X}$ such that $$\{Tf(n)\}\rightarrow g\in\mathcal{Y}$$ Let $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\sum_{n = N}^{\infty}n|f(n)| < \epsilon/4 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|g(n)| < \epsilon/4$$ Moreover, there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\lVert g - Tf_m\rVert < \epsilon/4 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \lVert f - f_m\rVert < \epsilon/4 N^{-1}$$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m \geq M$. It follows that \begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|Tf(n) - Tf_m(n)| &= \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}|nf(n) - nf_m(n)| + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|nf(n) - Tf_m(n)| \\ &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}n|f(n) - f_m(n)| + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}n|f(n)| + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|Tf_m(n)|\\ &< \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}N|f(n) - f_m(n)| + \epsilon/4 + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|Tf_m(n) - g(n)| + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|g(n)|\\ &< N\lVert f - f_m\rVert + \epsilon/4 + \lVert Tf_m - g\rVert + \epsilon/4\\ &< \epsilon
\end{align*} for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m\geq M$. Therefore, $\{Tf_n\}_{1}^{\infty}\rightarrow Tf$, so $T$ is closed.

For each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ define $f_m\in\mathcal{X}$ by $$f_m(n) :=  \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } m=n\\
0 & \text{if } m\neq n
\end{cases}$$
Then $\lVert f_m\rVert = 1$ but $$\lVert Tf_m\rVert = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|Tf_m(n)| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|nf_m(n)| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nf_m(n) = m$$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$. This shows that $T$ is not bounded.

c.) Note that $T$ is bijective. In fact, $T(g)=0$ then, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, $ng(n)=$, so $g(n)=0$ so $g=0$.  Thus $T$ is injective. Given any $f \in \mathcal{Y}$, let $g$ be defined by, for all  $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, $g(n) = n^{-1}f(n)$. It is clear that $g \in \mathcal{X}$ and $T(g)=f$. Thus $T$ is surjective. So we can define $S=T^{-1}$ and it is a bijective linear mapping from $\mathcal{Y}$ onto $\mathcal{X}$.

Clearly $Sf(n) = n^{-1}f(n)$ for all $f\in \mathcal{Y}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It follows that $$\lVert S f\rVert = \sum_{1}^{\infty}|Sf(n)| = \sum_{1}^{\infty}|n^{-1}f(n)| = \sum_{1}^{\infty}n^{-1}|f(n)| \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}|f(n)| = \lVert f\rVert$$ for all $f\in\mathcal{Y}$, so $S$ is bounded. Since $S = T^{-1}$, it is obvious that $S$ is surjective. If $S$ were open then $T$ would be continuous, which contradict b.).

Answer (score 2):

To show $X$ is a subspace just use the triangle inequality as it mentioned in the comment (by Vaidyanathan). We can think $L^1(\mu)$ as $l^1$. Observe that space of eventually zero sequence contained in $X$. As we know that space of eventually zero sequence is dense in $Y=l^1$, so $X$ will be dense. Moreover $Y$ is proper as $f(n)=\frac{1}{n^2}$ in $l^1$ but not in $X$ (As $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is not convergent). Hence $X$ is not complete.

Consider $\{f_j\}$ where each $f_j=(0,0,...0,1,0....)$ i.e, $1$ is in j-th position. Clearly $\{f_j\}$ is bounded sequence. Then $T(f_n(n))=(0,0,...,0,n,0,....)$. For $n\to \infty$, $||Tf_n||\to \infty$. So $T$ is not bounded. To show $T$ is closed you can use sequential criterion.

Here $Sf(n)=\frac{1}{n}f(n)$. Then it is easy to see that $\sum \frac{1}{n}|f(n)|\leq \sum |f(n)|$ i.e, $||S f||_1\leq ||f||_1$. So $S$ is bounded. Surjectivity follows from definition of $X$. It is not open by (b).

Comment: Excuse me, can you please explain how can we consider $L^1(\mu)$ as $l^1$ because I really can not see the reason behind it.

Comment: Try to use definition of counting measure in $L^1$.